# Unity: draw in game view

Tags: unity-game-engine

i want to draw guidlines in game view like in cinemacine
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6jK8.png)

Ive tried `Handles.DrawLine` and `GUI.DrawTexture` but they only shows up in scene view not game view

how do i do it

Answer (score 0):

You can try using line renderers of the Unity UI System.
Here's an example of how to edit a line from script.

```
LineRenderer lineRenderer;

void Start()
{
    lineRenderer = gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
    lineRenderer.positionCount = 2;
    lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, new Vector3(0, 0, 0));
    lineRenderer.SetPosition(1, new Vector3(10, 10, 10));
}
```